# Android POI Error when reading Microsoft Word document: Provider com.bea.xml.stream.EventFactory not found

Tags: android, kotlin, apache-poi

I am trying to use Apache POI in my Android application so that I can read MS Word files. I am integrating the POIA library which enables Apache POI usage on Android (https://github.com/SUPERCILEX/poi-android). However, when I run my code and read in a Word file, I receive the following error:

> org.apache.poi.javax.xml.stream.FactoryConfigurationError: Provider
>   com.bea.xml.stream.EventFactory not found

Below is my code (I am receiving error on the first line):

```
var document = XWPFDocument(uri?.let { contentResolver.openInputStream(it) });
var extractor = XWPFWordExtractor(document);
var documentText = extractor.text; // Retrieve the document's text
```

Below is my gradle (project-level):

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.60'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
    ext {
        poiVersion = '3.17'
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools:r8:1.4.93'
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Below is my gradle (app-level):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.diffchecker"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    // For developers using the Android Support Library
    implementation 'pub.devrel:easypermissions:2.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:18.3.0'
    implementation "com.github.SUPERCILEX.poi-android:poi:$poiVersion"
}
```

Below is the full stack trace:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.diffchecker, PID: 2292
    org.apache.poi.javax.xml.stream.FactoryConfigurationError: Provider com.bea.xml.stream.EventFactory not found
        at org.apache.poi.javax.xml.stream.FactoryFinder.newInstance(FactoryFinder.java:72)
        at org.apache.poi.javax.xml.stream.FactoryFinder.find(FactoryFinder.java:178)
        at org.apache.poi.javax.xml.stream.FactoryFinder.find(FactoryFinder.java:92)
        at org.apache.poi.javax.xml.stream.XMLEventFactory.newInstance(XMLEventFactory.java:30)
        at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.internal.marshallers.PackagePropertiesMarshaller.<clinit>(PackagePropertiesMarshaller.java:41)
        at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.init(OPCPackage.java:161)
        at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.<init>(OPCPackage.java:141)
        at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage.<init>(ZipPackage.java:97)
        at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.open(OPCPackage.java:324)
        at org.apache.poi.util.PackageHelper.open(PackageHelper.java:37)
        at org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument.<init>(XWPFDocument.java:116)
        at com.example.diffchecker.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.kt:249)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:7759)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4598)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4647)
        at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityResultItem.execute(ActivityResultItem.java:49)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1948)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7045)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:964)
```

Comment: var document = XWPFDocument()uri?.let{contentResolver.openInputStream(it.document)};


The let function will be called only if the value is non-null, so you use the parameter as a non-null argument of the lambda:


email?.let { email -> sendEmailTo(email) }

Comment: this isn't duplicate of this?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56088744/provider-com-bea-xml-stream-eventfactory-not-found-when-loading-xlsx-file

Comment: @Antonio I get the following error: Unresolved reference: document

Answer (score 1):

This is a common issue on Android, because this Java class is not supported:

> Provider `com.bea.xml.stream.EventFactory` not found.

You'll have to add `com.fasterxml:aalto-xml` and exclude `stax2-api-4.1.jar`:

```
// implementation "com.fasterxml:aalto-xml:1.1.0"
implementation ("com.github.SUPERCILEX.poi-android:poi:3.17" {
    exclude group: "org.codehaus.woodstox", module: "stax2-api"
}
```

And then update the system-properties:

```
init {
    System.setProperty("org.apache.poi.javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory", "com.fasterxml.aalto.stax.InputFactoryImpl")
    System.setProperty("org.apache.poi.javax.xml.stream.XMLOutputFactory", "com.fasterxml.aalto.stax.OutputFactoryImpl")
    System.setProperty("org.apache.poi.javax.xml.stream.XMLEventFactory", "com.fasterxml.aalto.stax.EventFactoryImpl")
}
```

In Java this would be the `static` keyword. In Kotlin on `init` should still be early enough.

Comment: Is init in the project-level or app-level gradle?

Comment: I now receive the following error when I try to sync the gradle after running the new implementations you listed: Could not find method com.github.SUPERCILEX.poi-android:poi:3.17() for arguments [build_difqk8gm93tw0xwozq61wfhvq$_run_closure2$_closure7@71491403] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

Comment: this question has been here for a long
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56088744/provider-com-bea-xml-stream-eventfactory-not-found-when-loading-xlsx-file

Comment: @AdamLee The system-properties need to be updated at run-time, with Kotlin or Java.

Comment: @MartinZeitler This results in the follwoing error: Duplicate class com.fasterxml.aalto.AsyncByteArrayFeeder found in modules aalto-xml-1.1.0.jar (com.fasterxml:aalto-xml:1.1.0) and poi-3.17.jar (com.github.SUPERCILEX.poi-android:poi:3.17)

Comment: It's because it is already included (and therefore doesn't need to be added).

Answer (score 1):

I managed to run ann app having a configuration similar to yours successfully.

1. Firstly, I excluded **stax** from **poi-android** because it may be outdated (and thus cause the issue) it's not actually required anymore for Java 6 and higher.

#### app/build.gradle

```
implementation ("com.github.SUPERCILEX.poi-android:poi:$poiVersion") {
    exclude group: 'stax', module: 'stax-api'
}
```

2. Secondly, in my `Application` class, I updated 3 system properties as follows:

#### MainApplication.kt

```
override fun onCreate() {
    super.onCreate()
    System.setProperty("org.apache.poi.javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory", "com.fasterxml.aalto.stax.InputFactoryImpl")
    System.setProperty("org.apache.poi.javax.xml.stream.XMLOutputFactory", "com.fasterxml.aalto.stax.OutputFactoryImpl")
    System.setProperty("org.apache.poi.javax.xml.stream.XMLEventFactory", "com.fasterxml.aalto.stax.EventFactoryImpl")
    ...
}
```

3. Finally, I built and ran the app -> it opened successfully.

Comment: This results in the following error when I open a word document: org.apache.poi.javax.xml.stream.FactoryConfigurationError: Provider com.bea.xml.stream.EventFactory not found

Comment: @AdamLee So, your original problem has turned into a runtime crash, right?

Answer (score 0):

Included Aalto, an open-source JSR173 provider by adding this to app's gradle

```
implementation group: 'com.fasterxml', name: 'aalto-xml', version: '1.0.0'
```

Then POI to use Aalto with the following code (Put this in my Application's onCreate(), but I assume anywhere else before using Poiji is fine as well.

```
    System.setProperty("org.apache.poi.javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory","com.fasterxml.aalto.stax.InputFactoryImpl");
System.setProperty("org.apache.poi.javax.xml.stream.XMLOutputFactory", "com.fasterxml.aalto.stax.OutputFactoryImpl");
System.setProperty("org.apache.poi.javax.xml.stream.XMLEventFactory", "com.fasterxml.aalto.stax.EventFactoryImpl");
```

And now my app is correctly reading XLSX files

Comment: This unfortunately, does not work. I am trying to read word files, not excel files.

Comment: If it's from content resolver error please try this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43994632/6160172